# programming calendar api for android from api10

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

i have followed google docs and many other sites and did the programming for calendar but it is not working for devices below android api v14... can anyone give the code for calendar api which can support all devices above api v10....

MainActivity.java

```
package com.test.weekly;
import java.text.Format;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Cursor mCursor = null;
private static final String[] COLS = new String[] { CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mCursor = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, null, null, null);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    onClick(findViewById(R.id.previous));
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data);
    String title = "N/A";
    Long start = 0L;
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.next:
        if(!mCursor.isLast()) mCursor.moveToNext();
        break;
    case R.id.previous:
        if(!mCursor.isFirst()) mCursor.moveToPrevious();
        break;
    }
    Format df = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this);
    Format tf = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this);
    try {
        title = mCursor.getString(0);
        start = mCursor.getLong(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //ignore
    }
    tv.setText(title+" on "+df.format(start)+" at "+tf.format(start));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has undocumented Calendar API that is supported on older devices.

[This is a tiny class](https://code.google.com/p/misc-android-tools/source/browse/com/atools/AndroidCalendar.java) to provide limited support of android Calendar. You can look into sources to understand how to work with Android calendar using undocumented API.

Complete project for Eclipse is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwvdX1pBENi1aXBPRXY5RG9mOGs/edit).

If you can read russian (or use translate.google.com), you can read [this topic](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108339/).